# how to rank data based on date grouped by year?

Tags: oracle11g, informatica-powercenter

My input data looks like below: 
Fisclyear__ date 
2011 ______7/1/2010 
2011 _____ 8/20/2010 
2011 ______2/30/2011 
2012 ______6/30/2011 
2012 ______8/15/2011 
2013 ______7/15/2013 
2013 ______7/30/2013

I need to rank data based on date in asc order and grouped by year, my result should be like below

Fisclyear__ date ______rank 
2011 ______7/01/2010___01 
2011 ______ 8/20/2010___02 
2011 ______2/30/2011___03 
2012 ______6/30/2011___01 
2012 ______8/15/2011___02 
2013 ______7/15/2013___01 
2013 ______7/30/2013___02

Comment: Well, what have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Oracle analytical function ROW_NUMBER () OVER PARTITION BY year ORDERBY date...i am couldn't find exact  syntax but it works

Answer (score 0):

Use a variable port in an expression in the following way:

```
v_rank = IIF(Fisclyear = v_prev_Fisclyear, v_rank + 1, 1)
v_prev_Fisclyear = Fisclyear
```

Now, create an output port:

```
rank = v_rank
```